# Query to find shortest route in Oracle

Tags: oracle, geospatial, spatial, shortest-path, oracle-spatial

I'm starting studies in Oracle 11g Spatial Databases and I want to know if is there a query that returns the shortest route (or path) between two points, or between a point and a linestring.

I have a map with some linestring (hiking trails) and Polygons (geographic accidents) and I want to find the shortest route between where I am now and the nearest trail while avoiding the accidents. I already have a query that returns me the nearest trail, but does not contours the accidents.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad idea to burden the oracle server at all with requests like this.

Optimization, decision and combinatorial algorithms should be run on Lingo, Lindo, Fortran or another specialist application.

Oracle should bother only with storing and retrieving data, not with otimization problems.

As Freud once said: "sometimes, a database is just a database". I was crazy upon thinking it could be something else, but now, thanks to this freudian insight, I'm sane.